# Why isnt my code executing after the for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

```
 while(counter != this.data.size()) {


      for(int i=0; i <= p.data.size(); i++) {
          double coefficient = first.getData().getCoefficient() * sec.getData().getCoefficient();
          int degree = first.getData().getDegree() + sec.getData().getDegree();
          Term current = new Term(coefficient,degree);


          if(ans.data.isEmpty()) {
              ans.data.addFirst(current);
          }
          else {
        boolean found = false;
        DNode<Term > tmp = ans.data.getFirst();

        while(found != true) {
            if(tmp.getData() == null) {
                ans.data.addLast(current);
                found = true;
            }
            else if(current.getDegree() > tmp.getData().getDegree()) {
                    ans.data.addBefore(current, tmp);
                    found = true;
                }
                else if(current.getDegree() == tmp.getData().getDegree()) {

                    double co = current.getCoefficient() * tmp.getData().getCoefficient();
                    int deg = current.getDegree() + tmp.getData().getDegree();
                    tmp.getData().setCoefficient(co);
                    tmp.getData().setDegree(deg);
                    found = true;
                }
             System.out.println("DID I GET HERE"); 
                tmp = tmp.getNext();
            }
         System.out.println("DID I GET HERE2"); 
        }
          System.out.println("DID I GET HERE3"); 
          sec = sec.getNext();
    }


      System.out.println("DID I GET HERE4"); 
          first = first.getNext();
          counter++;

      }
```

My code doesnt even reach the did i get here4 for some reason can anyone tell me why?
I am having a lot of difficulty as this project is due later today the code is suppose to multiply 2 polynomials

Comment: My guess would be that `counter != this.data.size()` is `false`, so the while loop body is never entered.

Comment: This is an incomplete code. How someone can say what is the problem? Try posting a [MCVE]

Comment: tried debugging it?

Comment: how is it incomplete?

Comment: @luistinoco it's incomplete in that sense that not all the (relevant) code is in your post